# How do I add a try catch block for a uiimageview that does not load an image?

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, try-catch, xcode4.4, ios

I am loading an image view from an online server (Google Sites in this case) based on what the user has selected from a table view (the table view is being populated from a plist which is loaded online). The code for that is already working but I'm trying to add an alert view for images that do not load. This is my Table View Controller.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize trailList;
@synthesize trailView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://sites.google.com/site/majorprojectgjk/Trails.plist"];
    trailList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [trailList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellid = @"trailCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellid];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellid];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [trailList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"pushView"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.trailView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        MapViewController *mvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        mvc.subjects = [trailList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

This would be my Map View Controller code.

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize map;
@synthesize subjects;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated];

    NSString *site = @"https://sites.google.com/site/majorprojectgjk/";
    NSLog(@"Display: %@", subjects);
    NSString *mapString = @"Map";
    NSString *png = @".png";
    //NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@%@",site, subjects, mapString, png];    

    @try
    {
        NSString *space = subjects;
        if ([space rangeOfString:@" "].location == NSNotFound)
        {
            NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@%@",site, subjects, mapString, png];
            map.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: url]]];
            NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"string contains space");
            NSString *removeSpace = [subjects stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@%@",site, removeSpace, mapString, png];
            map.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: url]]];
            NSLog(@"URL %@", url);
        }
    }

    @catch (NSException *ex) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"The map could not load!" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
    }

}
```

As I said earlier, the code for these are working perfectly fine. The image is downloading perfectly fine from the URL and the data is being parsed from the table view as well. I would like to know how to use a @try @catch block in order to alert the user that the UIImageView is empty (this happens when the URL is invalid and the map is not loaded into the server yet).

Comment: the `@try...@catch...@finally` blocks are **for catching the thrown exceptions only**. if you want to check the image is loaded or not (or any normal event in your application), you have to find another way (_delegates_, _notifications_, `if...then...else` ect...) because you are on a wrong path with these blocks in the current case.

Answer (score 0):

```
`enter code here`@catch(NSException *ex)
{
NSString *str=[ex copy];
//write code for alert
}
```

Comment: after writing the try block @catch(NSException *ex)
{
NSString *str=[ex copy];
//write code for alert                                     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:str delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
}

Comment: Can you try with only NSString *str=ex;and please paste the code what you wrote.